# Why QA tools aggregate info on "projects" and not "teams"?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, terminology, team-management, techniques

I'm currently evaluating a QA tool for our company's QA Team; I don't have much experience in this area so many things are new for me and probably there are many reasons for what I consider a design problem in our case.

The "problem" is that in all the tools I have seen or installed, the information is grouped project by project, and uses cases like getting a metric of how many tests were run in a week by each member of the team, independent of the project, requires me to build a report for each project and then aggregate the info outside of the tool (or make SQL Scripts to "add" the info).

Also, if we define a test like "withdraw from an mutual fund", and we want to use that definition in more than one project, let's say a standalone front-office application and an internet mobile application for our clients, then we have to re-write the test for each case. What I would expect here is to have a "test definition" and a "test implementation", so if I change the definition I get some kind of warning that the X number of implementations should be reviewed.

At the end, we need to manage a QA team, and to reuse knowledge where possible, but the "project" does not translate accurately to our needs, or maybe I am miss understanding many things and there is another way to organize info into "projects" that could meet our needs.

Any idea or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Who cares how great the team is doing when the project is failing. In the end it is always the value for the end-user that is important in software.

Comment: Agree Niels. We are always taking efforts to make project successful considering releases & objectives. Those are for Projects and Not for teams.

Voting to close

Comment: Basically because two mayor factors; if you are managing a team you need to know how well you are doing with your team, and project that info through months and even years. The other factor is that if a test is designed for business case, that test can and should be replicated across all software implementations, regardless of the project. A withdraw from a mutual fund is the same business case, that has different implementations in mobile, web, or front-end business app.